# How do I get the current folder path within an XSLT file?

Tags: xslt

Is there a way to get the current folder path from within a XSLT file?

I need it to locate other XML and XSLT files. We have different customer folders and will need to successfully find the correct files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can send it into the style-sheet from outside using [xsl:param](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_param.asp). Then you need to determine what the current path is when invoking the from the outside ;)

Answer (score 6):

In MSXSL on Windows, you can use a script extension like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:user="http://tempuri.org/msxsl"
>

  <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="user">
<![CDATA[
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

function getCurrentPath(){
  return fso.GetFolder(".").Path
}
]]>
  </msxsl:script>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="user:getCurrentPath()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Other XSL processors support similar methods to use external resources (scripting languages, function libraries etc.), so this is just an example.

Comment: Sorry for that. I voted it down for using non-standard extension, but after adding my answer, I realized that I suggested the same thing. I think there is no 'standard' way to do it. (Except using params)

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way to get the current
>   folder path from within a xslt file?
>
> Need it to locate other xml and xslt
>   files

**No need for any extension functions or even parameters to do that!**

Any ***relative*** URLs used in the `href` attribute of an [**`<xsl:import>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#import) or [**`<xsl:include>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#include)
 instruction are resolved based on the URL of the current XSLT stylesheet -- it only needs to have an URL, which is vlearly stated as true in the question above. This is very convenient in importing/including XSLT stylesheets.

**The** [**`document()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document) **function also will resolve a relative URL in a similar way**, thus making any additional XML document accessible using anrelative URL.

**Lastly, here is** [**an example**](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-standardXpathFunctions.xsl?revision=1.9&view=markup&sortby=date) **how this facilities are massively used in a big library** of XSLT functions and templates ([**FXSL 2.x**](http://fxsl.sf.net)):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs xdt f"
>
<!--
       This module contains the FXSL versions of the "standard" XPath functions

       These are intended as convenience functions, so that they can be passed 
       as parameters to other functions (e.g. to f:zipWith())                  
       or curried and passed as parameters (e.g. to f:map())                   
-->

 <xsl:import href="func-curry.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-compose-flist.xsl"/>

 <xsl:import href="func-standardArithmeticXpathFunctions.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-standardBooleanXpathFunctions.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-standardStringXpathFunctions.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-standardNodesXpathFunctions.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-standardSequencesXpathFunctions.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-standardAggregateXpathFunctions.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-standardDateTimeXpathFunctions.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-standardXSLTXpathFunctions.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-standardAxisXpathFunctions.xsl"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right about imports, includes, document and relative paths. Extensions or parameters were suggested for getting current directory only.

Comment: If you're on Java, [watch out for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699860/resolving-relative-paths-when-loading-xslt-files/3700296#3700296) if you expect `<xsl:import>` or `<xsl:include>` to work properly!

Answer (score 6):

This may work for your setup:

```
<xsl:value-of select="system-property('user.dir')"/>
```

For example,

```
<xsl:value-of select="document(concat(system-property('user.dir'),'/',filename,'.xml'))//title[1]"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

no...
but you could maybe workaround the problem by using relative URLs and/or passing parameters into the stylesheet.

Answer (score 3):

In most XSLT processor, you can add custom functions as extensions. For example here is [Saxon's documentation](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensibility/intro.html) how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Not AFAIK (though you could always pass it as a param to the transform), but I'm not clear why relative paths won't work for you here.