# XSLT: How to get file names from a certain directory?

Tags: xml, xslt, file, filesystems

Is there a function in XSLT that can takes in a directory path and gives back all the files in it??

I have a xml file now reads like this

```
<filelist>
    <file>fileA.xml</file>
    <file>fileB.xml</file>
</filelist>
```

Now, there's directory called `dir`, has files `fileX.xml`, `fileY.xml` and a bunch of other xml files in it. I want to add these files on to the orginal xml file, so that I can get:

```
<filelist>
    <file>fileA.xml</file>
    <file>fileB.xml</file>
    <file>fileX.xml</file>
    <file>fileY.xml</file>
    .... <!-- other files -->
</filelist>
```

Is there an XSLT way to do this?? something that takes in a dir root, and is able to iterator through all of the files in it?? And then I could just call something like:

```
<xsl:element name = file >
     <xsl:copy> <!--whatever file name--> <xsl:copy>
</xsl:element>0
```

### [Edit-solution]

all of the answers were very helpful. I ended up finding an external solution (using saxon). I thought it may be helpful for other people to post my solution here, although it is very specific to my own situation.

I use Ant to build a java web app and need to translate some xml files before deployment. Hence, I was using the `xslt` task to do the job by adding the "saxon9.jar" in the classpath. And in my xsl file, I just did something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="collection('../dir/?select=*.xml')" >
     <xsl:element name='file'>
        <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()]"/>
     </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Do you want the XSLT engine to go off to the filesystem and get the list of files within the directory???  That's not really what XSLT was designed for.  Mush better to have the "host" application do that, generate the XML and then use XLST to transform it into the output format.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. You should post it as an answer so that we can upvote it. :-)

Comment: Also, note that collection() is not specific to Saxon. It's part of XSLT 2.0 in general. Also note that it only works for XML documents... you can't e.g. get a directory of .mp3 files using collection().

Comment: Good Q. Glad you stuck to your original desire to do it in XSL when other suggested it's the wrong tool. Once you figured it out, it turned out to be pretty simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XSLT has nothing built-in for this task. XSLT is a transformation language - for dynamic output you generally need a transformation *source* that contains everything already (just in a different form) – you cannot create XML from nothing.

The three ways you can tackle the problem are:

1. Build the XML in a programming language, leaving out XSLT altogether. This is the simplest way to get the result you want.
2. Build an XSL stylesheet that accepts a parameter, put a (pre-built) delimited list of files into that parameter, let the XSLT handle the string and make XML from it. This involves external handling as well, basically this is option 1., plus you'd have to write an XSL stylesheet that does string handling (something that XSL has not been geared to)
3. Use extension functions and do the directory processing from within the XSL. An example how to get started can be found in [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546152/xslt-get-the-file-current-folder-path/546247). This is not very portable as extension functions are platform specific.

It boils down to this:

- You *will* need help from an external programming language
- You do not *absolutely need* XSLT do accomplish the task, since XML output is all you need and no transformation is required.

Ergo: Don't use XSL for this.

Comment: This is no longer a correct answer. XPath 2.0 introduced the `collection()` function (see edited question).

Comment: @ChristianHujer In a perfect world you would be right, but unfortunately many XSLT implementations to this day are XSLT 1.0 only.

Comment: That's true. The only XSLT processor that I'm aware of that implements XSLT 2.0 / XPath 2.0 (and newer) is Saxon, all others that I know only implement XSLT 1.0 / XPath 1.0, sadly.

Comment: There are a few others that support up to version 3.0, so the situation is not as dire as it was back when I wrote this answer. But often you will find yourself stuck with 1.0 still.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in native XSLT, but various implementations allow you to add extensions to the functionality.

For example, in C# you can add a user defined URN:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet {snipped the usual xmlns stuff}
    xmlns:user="urn:user" >
```

then use the functions within "user"

```
  <xsl:value-of select="user:getdirectory( @mydir )" />
```

within the C# you associate "user" to a C# class:

```
 XSLThelper xslthelper      = new XSLThelper( );  // your class here
 xslArgs.AddExtensionObject( "urn:user", xslthelper );
```

and your class defines the "getdirectory" function:

```
public class XSLThelper
{
public string getdirectory(System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator xml, string strXPath, string strNULL)
{
       //blah
    }
}
```

Hugh amount of homework left here!  [MSDN Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302079.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The Q is six years old and answered.  Just throwing my 2 cents in for those who land here again.

I've needed an XML file representing the filenames in a directory. I've done it three ways:

1. XSLT 2.0 document() as others have pointed out in this thread. Drawback is performance as it reads the file into the dom parser, when all you really wanted is the name. Also as LarsH pointed out in the OP comments, this works only with valid XML files. If you have a non-xml or malformed xml file in the recurse, it crashes the transform.
2. The tool [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) with the command `xmlstarlet ls > filenames.xml`
3. A crude bash script I made up (it could be optimized):

```
DIRECTORY=$1
RESULTFILE=$2

# put the directory listing into a temp file
# modify the ls command for your needs
ls -A1 $DIRECTORY > /tmp/zFiles.txt

# remove detritus and wrap the lines in <file> elements
sed -i -e's/^[^$]*$/   <file filename="&"\/>/' /tmp/zFiles.txt

# build the file
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' > $RESULTFILE
echo "<files>" >> $RESULTFILE
cat /tmp/zFiles.txt >> $RESULTFILE
echo "</files>" >> $RESULTFILE
```

I had used the bash script for a long time but now I use the xmlstarlet method exclusively.  The result starlet file contains specific file attributes such as permissions and dates, I have found that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [document()](http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/func_document.asp) function to read the XML files in. I'm not sure how well it is supported on various XSLT engines though.

This is a [good example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipcombxslt/) showing it in use.

But that doesn't address the problem of reading in the names of the files from the directory. The other answer gives a way of doing that side of it.