# XSL import causing FileNotFoundException in web application

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a simple web application under websphere5. Under `appDir\WEB-INF\classes\` I have these files:

- `main.xslt`
- `templates.xslt`

`main.xslt` contains the instruction

```
<xsl:import href="templates.xsl" />
```

but the application fails when `main.xslt` is used in Java code. How should I specify the path to imported XSL files if they all are in the same folder (`WEB-INF\classes\`)?

Text of exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: d:\Program Files\WebSphere\AppServer1\templates.xsl (The system cannot find the file specified.
>   )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide a custom uri-resolver to process the includes.  In a web application, there's no guarantee that a filesystem is accessible, as you could be running out of a WAR file.  Take a look at the [javax.xml.transform.URIResolver](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/URIResolver.html) interface and [Transformer.setURIResolver()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setURIResolver%28javax.xml.transform.URIResolver%29)

Comment: Correct but general answer, missing explanation: the relative uri for `xsl:import` declaration will be resolved with stylesheet URI as Base URI. Whether the XSLT proccesor can handle that URI scheme or it has right privileges, it's another issue. From : http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#import *The `xsl:import` element has an `href` attribute whose value is a URI reference identifying the stylesheet to be imported. A relative URI is resolved relative to the base URI of the `xsl:import` element*

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you loaded the **main.xsl**, [you may need to set the `SystemID` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699860/resolve-relative-paths-when-loading-xslt-files/3700296#3700296), so that it can resolve the relative path.

Comment: You're a lifesaver!